# Is there a way to make Ctrl + Enter behave exactly the same way as Enter in div with contenteditable true

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, contenteditable

I have tried many answers from SO for this, but none are perfect. Is there a good solution for this?

**Edit 1:** I have tried this code:

```
if (event.keyCode === 13 && event.ctrlKey) {
    //console.log("enterKeyDown+ctrl");
    // $(editor).append('<div><br></div>');
    event.preventDefault();
    if (window.getSelection) {
        let selection = window.getSelection(),
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
            br = document.createElement("br");
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(br);
        range.setStartAfter(br);
        range.setEndAfter(br);
        range.collapse(false);
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        return false;
    }

}
```

But the problem is, when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> at the end of line, the cursor doesn't go down although inspecting it shows that there's a `<br>` below it. Plessing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the mid of text works fine.

Comment: Your code ?? What have you tried?

Comment: I have just added the code

Comment: I'm recommending to close this as too broad. You haven't said what you don't like about the answers you have found, and also what your criteria are

Comment: I just mentioned the problem, that I have with the code above. Pressing Ctrl + Enter at end of line doesn't result in cursor going to the new line. Instead, it remains where it was. If I press Ctrl + Enter in mid of text, it works fine.